# Combining & matching output from Get-AzureADUser, Get-AzureADSubscribedSku , Get-AzureADUserManager

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, azure-active-directory, office365

## Problem & what i have now

---

#### The script

*comments are in norwegian btw, if they look strange lol*

```
Connect-AzureAD

#variabel
$Users = Get-AzureADUser -All:$true | where-object { $null -ne $_.AssignedLicenses.SkuId } | Sort-Object CompanyName, UserPrincipalName| Select-Object -Property CompanyName, DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, Department, Mobile, TelephoneNumber

#formatting
$userlistTable = $Users | Format-Table 
$userlistHTML = $Users | ConvertTo-Html

#outputs
$userlistHTML > out.html # ut som HTML
$userlistTable > out.txt # ut som Tabell i .txt
$userlistTable           # ut som Tabell i terminal
```

#### My output as it stands right now:

```
CompanyName        DisplayName        UserPrincipalName          Department        Mobile          TelephoneNumber
-----------        -----------        -----------------          ----------        ------          ---------------
Company inc        Usser Name         username@website.com        Callsenter        12345678        87654321
```

What i would like. is a table that has all the info in the output of `$Users` to inclide the users "SkuPartNumber". 
The field u get by running the command `Get-AzureADSubscribedSku | Select -Property SkuPartNumber`

I would also like to get the users "manager", that u get by running `Get-AzureADUserManager`.

that last command uses the users Object ID to find their manager.
And to be honest, im very lost on how to combine these commands into one table.

---

its not the end of the world as it is right now. i could of just have multiple tables but having to manually cross reference these takes some time.

Im really not sure why these things are split into different commands to be honest. i get that a license is via 365 and not azure. but it seems a little backwards that i cant see the licenses from the command showing me all the user information. when a user class in powershell DOES infact show the **sku ID**. its burried within `AssignedLicenses` from running the command:

```
Get-AzureADUser | where-object -property UserPrincipalName -eq "emailhere@domain.com" | FL
```

This will give you among other things, this info:

```
AssignedLicenses               : {class AssignedLicense {
                                   DisabledPlans: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
                                   SkuId: 3b555118-da6a-4418-894f-7df1e2096870
                                 }
```

### conclusion

I know this was a long read. and if u made it this far im sorry.
any help with this would be amazing. This might be super easy to do, but im very far from a powershell wiz. thanks again for reading, and any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional properties to selected objects with calculated properties like `Select @{label='name';expression={foo}}`

```sh
$Users = Get-AzureADUser -All:$true

$Users | Where-Object { $_.AssignedLicenses.SkuId } | 
  Select-Object -Property UserPrincipalName,  ## other properties here...
    @{l='ManagerUPN';e={($_ | Get-AzureADUserManager).UserPrincipalName}},
    @{l='AssignedSKUs';e={$_.AssignedLicenses.SkuId -join ';'}}


UserPrincipalName ManagerUPN         AssignedSKUs                                                                                                  
----------------- ----------         ------------                                                                                                  
user@domain.com   manager@domain.com 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000;11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
```

It can be slow to run `Get-AzureADUserManager` for every user, but that's how azure stores the relationships.

When you have a **lot** of users, it can be slightly faster to get the manager users first, then use `Get-AzureADUserDirectReport -all $true` to expand all the `directreports` in one call. The `Microsoft.Graph.Users` module is also a bit more lightweight

Comment: yeah graph is the way to go. its part of something old someone else wrote. and i hoped to maybe improve what they had. but at this point redoing it with graph is way better.