# Get direct and indirect reports of person x with Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am looking to populate direct (and indirect) subordinates under a specific person to crosscheck/update O365 DLs.

I want to populate people reporting under Bob but the script stop after it arrives at Frank (F), and I need help on how we can capture everyone in Bob's organization because the cmdlet, by default, only capture direct report under target person, how can we loop until the person without a direct report...

```
Bob has 3 direct reports (Chad, Dean, Eason)
Chad has 1 direct report (Frank)
Dean has 0 direct report
Eason has 1 direct report (George)
George has 1 direct report (Harris)
```

```
B > C > F
B > D
B > E > G > H
```

```
$name = Read-Host -Prompt "Name: "
$dog= Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $name

$puppets = Get-AzureADUserDirectReport -ObjectID $dog.ObjectId |
    Where-Object {
        ($_.UserPrincipalName) -notlike "*svc*" -and
        ($_.UserPrincipalName) -notlike "SVC*"
        }

$org+=$puppets

Foreach ($puppet in $puppets){
 $target = Get-AzureADUserDirectReport -ObjectID $puppet.ObjectId -ErrorAction Ignore |
    Where-Object {
        ($_.UserPrincipalName) -notlike "*svc*" -and
        ($_.UserPrincipalName) -notlike "SVC*"
        }
 $org+=$target
 }
```

I am currently stuck on the first puppet manager and hope someone can guide me on moving to another puppet until no direct report is left.

Comment: can you explain in detail of what you are trying to do?

Comment: `($_.UserPrincipalName) -notlike "*svc*")` should be enough; no need for the `-and ($_.UserPrincipalName) -notlike "SVC*")` since `-notlike` works case-insensitively and the asteriks means none or multiple characters

Comment: Hi @kavyaSaraboju I have updated my question, hope it gives everyone better picture on what am I trying to achieve, thank you!

Comment: You have a tree and need to get all the managers at the root of the tree.  Usually in these case the root either has a single parent manager (sometimes zero)  or the parent is null..  I think in this case you want to have a for loop that gets all managers that report to Bob.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the same in my environment.

I could get the direct report itself as you did

```
$user= Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $name

Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId "xxxxxx1"

 Get-AzureADUserDirectReport  |
    Where-Object {
        ($user.UserPrincipalName) -like "*ya*" 
        }
```

[image]

To get indirect reports there is no straight methods in order to loop through all organization .
We need to loop by checking with user and user manager first and then repeat

Commands:

```
$users= Get-AzureADUser -Top 10
foreach($user in $users)
{
$usermanager =Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId  $user.ObjectId
{
Get-AzureADUserDirectReport -ObjectId $usermanager.ObjectId
}

}
```

[image]

You can check the user manager and then check the direct reports in a loop

Also check this  [azure - Combining & matching output from Get-AzureADUser, Get-AzureADSubscribedSku , Get-AzureADUserManager - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477562/combining-matching-output-from-get-azureaduser-get-azureadsubscribedsku-get/74482188#74482188)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have managed so far by copying & pasting from another AD Sample.
It would be cool if we could make the "Manager" field shows canonical order like...

```
B > C > F
B > D
B > E > G > H
```

Instead of

```
C
B
G
```

```
Function Get-DirectReport3 {

    # https://thesysadminchannel.com/get-direct-reports-in-active-directory-using-powershell-recursive/
    # 1. Run this script (F5) first
    # 2. Issue a command Get-DirectReport3 <Object-ID> to get output
    # 3. Alternatively, Get-DirectReport3 <Object-ID> | Out-GridView for better visibilty

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $false,
            ValueFromPipeline = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
        )]
        [string]  $ObjectId,
        [switch]  $NoRecurse
    )
    BEGIN {}
    PROCESS {
        $manager = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $ObjectId
        $UserAccount = Get-AzureADUserDirectReport -ObjectID $manager.ObjectId | 
                            select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,@{n="Manager";e={(Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId (Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $_.ObjectId).ObjectId).DisplayName}},ObjectID
        $UserAccount | 
            ForEach-Object {

                $User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.ObjectId | 
                            select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,@{n="Manager";e={(Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $_.ObjectId).DisplayName}},ObjectID 
                if ($null -ne $User.UserPrincipalName) {
                    if (-not $NoRecurse) {
                        Get-DirectReport3 $User.ObjectId
                        }
                }

                [PSCustomObject] @{
                    ObjectId           = $User.ObjectId
                    UserPrincipalName  = $User.UserPrincipalName
                    DisplayName        = $User.DisplayName
                    Manager            = $User.Manager
                }
            }
        }
    END {}}
```